# Inserting html code when Text area value not showing with Inspect Element

Tags: html, inspector

I am inserting html code of my inspector but when I right click and inspect element to see values. Normally, I insert HTML by inspect element and edit as html and paste code. But Now My current value which I type in textarea is showing.

I tried to highlight my current value and if it shown I right click and edit as html and paste my code.
But now no current html value showing and unable to insert html code.

`<textarea class="gwt-TextArea F0XO1GC-Nb-g" rows="10" id="gwt-uid-811" dir="ltr"></textarea>`

When I right click to select my current value. It did't show value but above code. and in above code No value is showing.

Comment: You cannot add HTML inside textarea. Textarea can only have text inside it.

Comment: Okay but why the value I write in text area not showed when inspect element. How to make it show me that value?

Answer (score 2):

Once textarea can only store text content, you should give the value with '' couse the html contains "".

```js
document.getElementById("gwt-uid-811").value = '<divclass="myclass">my_content</div>';
```

```html
<textarea class="gwt-TextArea F0XO1GC-Nb-g" rows="10" id="gwt-uid-811" dir="ltr"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi Lucas Sir, It is now giving me value when I put it in console. But How to insert html code in to it. Thank you. Sorry I am new sir.